# How to make white aioli?

Tags: eggs, sauce

Whenever I make aioli with the traditional recipe of egg and oil it always turns out yellowish. It's obviously because of the color of the egg yolks. However, recently I've noticed some good restaurants serving quality aioli that is really white. Also some store bought ones are more white than yellow.

I'm wondering how they make the aioli to be that white instead of the golden version I always get.

Answer (score 10):

The original [Valencian allioli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aioli#Allioli) and [Maltese aljoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltese_cuisine#History) [don't have egg yolk in its receipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aioli). Egg yolk makes emulsification easier but it isn't necessary. Garlic itself is already an emulsifier.

Allioli is made by pounding garlic with olive oil and salt in a mortar until smooth. The oil should be added little by little -- otherwise the emulsion breaks.

[image]

Comment: Mortar and pestle?!? Maybe if you've got all day (or if you want to be excessively traditional). I'll take a few pulses in a food processor.

Comment: Allright, thanks. I'll give it a try without the eggs. But indeed, in my food processor instead of the mortar.

Comment: On second thought, you reckon this will result in the white version I'm talking about? I mean, Te olive oil is golden of color as well?

Comment: @tomvo I have the impression that the oil doesn't make the emulsion as yellow as the oil is yellow in the non-emulsified state. See image [aioli with egg yolk](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Allioli.jpg) and [allioli without egg yolk](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Catalan_allioli.jpg). It is still yellowish. The color obviously depends on the used oil. The caption of the last image says that there are lighter or darker olive oils and some even make the allioli greenish.

Comment: Traditional All i oli is hand made with mortar and pestle. Its colour is yellowish, even with green oils (it's greenier than the one made with yellow oils). Allioli made in food processors has white colour.

Comment: More than one year later serious eats comes with this post: http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/10/how-to-make-egg-white-mayonnaise.html. Super white mayo base, I should try this with added garlic and see how the flavor ends up to be.

Comment: When choosing oil, the more it looks like clear drinking water when you start, the whiter the end product would be when compared to an oil that has color is not clear.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of commercial mayonnaises/aiolis use whole eggs, which doesn't darken the mixture as much as egg yolks alone. The restaurants you speak of could be doing the same.

Also, what kind of oil are you using? When I use sunflower oil in aioli, it's lighter than something like olive oil.

Alternatively, ChefSteps etc. use `titanium dioxide` to make things whiter, you could try that.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain their reason why?

Comment: maybe because of this: "I use sunflower oil in aioli"?

Comment: Sunflower oil is pretty commonly used for aioli - it's definitely a close second to olive oil.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some restaurante do the original without eggs to also get covered with Vegan clients.

When I do it with mortar, with 12 grains of garlic and salt, just until paste. Then adding sunflower oil, little by little, I get a pure white and thick all-i-oli (means garlic and oil).

Sometimes, the emulsión fails, so I mend it by adding a boiled potato or some soft bread. It results much stronger than garlic mayonaise.

Comment: surely you mean olive oil?